# Java as a digital forensics environment

Tags: java, computer-forensics

Just wondering if anyone out there has any experiance working with java (as appose to c/c++) in a digital forensics environment and if so could they advise me as to problems or advantages they may have encountered? 
Cheers

Comment: Do you mean doing forensics on Java applications or using Java applications to do forensics on other data?

Comment: Hi leonm, What I suppose I really me is using java to do forensics on other data. Like encase or the sleuth kit. Those as far as I'm aware are done in C/C++/Perl and I am trying to look at the possabilitys of doing something similar in Java and am trying to figure out the limitations or advantages......
Example)
Takeing a disk image (possibly bit for bit) and then analysing with an app designed and programmed in Java.
Hope this clarifys.

Comment: Based on your clarification, overall you tend to have a bit more flexibility with going down to the "bare metal" with languages like C, but who knows, someone might write these sorts of things in Java.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do it all in Java, if there are something that must be done in C , you have JNI package through which you can call 'dangerous' routines. Java grants you robustness, security model,scalability is not big issue... you don't have to cope with 64 bit OS, or optimizing your code to take advantage of multiples CPU-s, you will find it odd but true: your software might run faster in Java than in C. If you are not average developer, if you are familiar with CPU structure, understand machine code and handling with registers thorughly, then forget my text, you might have it done better in C.

Comment: Nope, taking it on as a project. Should be interesting to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

We have been moving our forensics code from C++ and Python to Java for the following reasons:

- We are concerned about how corrupt data may impact our tools; with Java it is less of an issue.
- Single Java binary will run on 32bit and 64bit systems
- Better exploitation of threads.

Our initial results are quite promising: bulk_extractor ported from C++ to Java ran 3x faster! We were amazed. We think that this is because jflex produces a faster FSM than flex.

The main problem is that there are no good open source Java forensic file systems, and there are no JNI bindings for SleuthKit. One of our workarounds is to extract all of the metadata from a disk image using fiwalk into an XML blob and then process the XML in java.

To download these tools, check out http://afflib.org/

Comment: We actually gave up on Java.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with binary parsing and arbitrary string parsing is really painful in Java and quite unnecessary. Java's lack of unsigned integer is really annoying as well.

We use python for everything in house as its trivial to code (especially compared to the bulkiness of java), struct.pack/unpack makes parsing of binary data simple, the built in data structures / objects, and the fact that they are libraries for nearly everything we need

I really couldn't recommend Java for forensics processing

edit:

also a number of forensics tools are either already in python or have python bindings (volatility, sleuthkit, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm wondering why you could not create struct.pack and struct.unpack in Java...

Answer (score 1):

The Sleuth Kit now has JNI bindings.  They are not officially released, but you can find them on the github master branch. A SQLite database is populated by the C++ code with file system metadata and then Java code queries the database and makes corresponding Java objects. JNI is used to get the file content into the Java side.  Autopsy 3 (which is a Java NetBeans RCP app) uses the bindings.